# Como pegar um dado de um item selecionado do combobox html

Tags: php, html5, combobox

Boa dia Pessoal.
Galera é o seguinte, são duas perguntas a seguir. 
tenho 2 combobox! 
No 1º combobox tenho todas as empresas do sistema. aqui tudo ok.
No 2º combobox tenho todas as filias da empresa selecionada pelo 1º combobox. segue a funcao do 2 combo box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function uniopcao()
        {     
            $(document).ready(function() 
            { 
                var unid = $('#Unidades option:selected').val();
                var tensao = $('#Unidades option:selected').text();
                alert(tensao);
                $('#una').load('/site/unidade.php?uni='+ unid);
                $('#una').load('/site/unidade.php?ten='+ tensao);

            });
        }
        </script>
```

reparem que eu preciso do valor da segunda combobox e também do texto da segunda combobox.  e onde surge o 1º problema... 
Nessa parte do código `var tensao = $('#Unidades option:selected').text();`
esse text() me retorna o seguinte:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
e no alert que eu peço para exibir  me retorna o seguite:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

reparem que no alert ele me exibe dois  valores o "mt" e o 429....
agora intendam por favor  como eu faço pra pegar apenas o valor "mt" no código seguinte `var tensao = $('#Unidades option:selected').text("eu queria o apenas o mt  e não tudo mt-429");`

se tiver como?  eu gostaria de saber por favor ...
já na segunda duvida... que eu só vou continuar porque e relativa a mesma questão e o seguinte 
na segunda combobox pode existir uma ou mais filiais cadastradas...  como na imagem a seguir:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando tem só uma filial gera um erro no retorno. que eu faço no seguinte select via pagina php segue o código:

```
<?php                       
session_start();
    include("conexao.php");           

            $unidade = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'au', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
            $_SESSION['ulala'] = $_GET['au'];

            $comandoSql = "SELECT a,  b, c, Tensao
                            FROM Tab_UC where cod='".$ugauga."'" ;

            $dados = mysql_db_query($bancoDados, $comandoSql) or die (mysql_error());

            //$a='<option value="Selecione">Selecione sua Unidade: </option> ' ; 
            while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($dados))
            {
               // $a.= '<option value="Selecione">Selecione sua Unidade: </option> ' ; 

                $a.='<option value= "'.$linha["a"].'">'.$linha["Tensao"].'-'.$linha["b"].'</option>';        
            }
            echo $a; 

?>
```

esse erro faz com que as empresas que só tenham uma unica filial, não consigam ver um  resultado de um outro select via outra pagina php que não vem ai caso..
e as empresas que tem mais de uma filial eu escolho  segunda filial e mostra corretamente...
eu preciso que essa linha de código.//
 `$a.= '<option value="Selecione">Selecione sua Unidade: </option> ' ;` 
seja apresentada no 1º lugar da combobox 
se intenderam me ajude pf.

Comment: @Diego, não entendi sua edição...

Comment: @Victor Gomes a edição conflitou com a sua, tentei identar o código, que tava dificil de entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar somente os dois primeiros caracteres, use assim:

```js
var tensao = $('#Unidades option:selected').text().substr(0, 2);
```

Comment: exatamente isso!!!! parabéns  muito agradecido